# Jupyter Notebook Pivottablejs Multiple Instances

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pivot-table, multiple-instances, pivottable.js

**Intro**

I am using a library that generates interactive pivot table/chart in Jupyter Notebook. This library was developed by [@nicolaskruchten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112871/nicolaskruchten)
Also see documentations on [Github](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs)

**A Description Of The Problem**

What I want to do is to call pivot_ui() multiple times within a single notebook page, by selecting "Run All" option under 'Cell'. Each time pivot_ui() is called, I pass different input data into it, and I am hoping to get different pivot charts/tables, each reflecting its corresponding input data.

test1.csv and test2.csv are 2 different data files. I want to create pivot charts on a same notebook page, subsequently.
Here's my code:

```py
# Cell 1
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui

df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
pivot_ui(df)
```

```py
# cell 2
df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
pivot_ui(df2)
```

If I run cell1 code only, then I get the pivot chart below.
[image]

If I run cell2 code only, then I get the pivot chart below.
[image]

If I run all cells, then the pivot chart for test1.csv is overwritten with test2.csv data, as shown below.
[image]

Is it possible to run all the cells, calling pivot_ui() multiple times with different input data each time, and display them accordingly in the notebook?

** Things I Have Tried**

1. I have looked through documentations on [pivotUI](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters#options-object-for-pivotui), but I haven't found an input argument addresses this challenge.
2. I searched 'pivot_ui' in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and I can confirm no one else has asked the same questions.

I appreciate any suggestions/comments from the all mighty Internet community!

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Set outfile_path keyword argument to a unique value for each pivot plot.

In the following example, test1.csv will generate pivottable_test1.html; test2.csv will generate pivottable_test2.html. Both html files are saved to disk. Jupyter notebook will show 2 different plots.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
from IPython.display import HTML
df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv",)
pivot_ui(df1, outfile_path='pivottable_test1.html')

df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv",)
pivot_ui(df2, outfile_path='pivottable_test2.html')
```

Special thanks to Manusri Viswanathan for this solution.

Also see the solution provided by the author [@nicolaskruchten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112871/nicolaskruchten) via this [link](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/issues/65).